# Access Google Sheets on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, google-sheets-api

Hi I am using [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) (similar to Jupyter Notebook). Does anyone know how to access data from Google Sheets using Google Colaboratory notebook?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loading data from Google Sheets is covered in the I/O example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=sOm9PFrT8mGG

Answer (score 11):

```
!pip install --upgrade -q gspread


import gspread
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from google.auth import default

creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)


worksheet = gc.open('data_set.csv').sheet1
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

Comment: google sheet has .gsheet extension, when I am following above steps, it is throwing SpreadsheetNotFound error

Comment: @ratnesh, you need to enter the sheet name exactly as it appears in Google sheets. No need for any extensions. In the example above the sheet is actually called 'data_set.csv'

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [gspread_pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) interface:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread_pandas
from google.auth import default
import pandas as pd
creds, _ = default()

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['T'])
##create new sheet and dump dataframe
spread = gspread_pandas.Spread('New Spreadsheet Name', creds=creds, create_spread=True)
spread.df_to_sheet(df, index=False, headers=True, start='A1',)
## open existing spreadsheet
spreadsheetId = '1DayucszOBJhOT1rNdfdft919tp20os'
spread = gspread_pandas.Spread(spreadsheetId, creds=creds,)
##grab data into dataframe
df = spread.sheet_to_df(index=0,start_row=2)
```